# Rails HABTM checkbox validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models with a joinging table (bowsers_profiles). (HABTM) ie.

```
model Profile
  has_and_belongs_to_many :browsers
end

model Browser
  has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles
end
```

On saving the profile the user can select what browsers they use. How can I validate it so that the user must select at least one browser. Will the validation belong on profile. Im guessing it would?

Can anyone shed the light on how to achieve this.

Thanks if you can.

Comment: Hi Preacher.  It didn't work what you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was count the array elements for HABTM fields ie,

```
  def must_have_at_least_one_browser
    errors.add(:base, 'You must select at least one browser') unless browser_ids.count > 0
  end
```

Simple solution in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in the model that corresponds to the controller that contains the action where you select the relationships. For example, if you select browsers in the `profile#new` and/or `profile#edit` actions, I'd put the validation in the profile model.

Here's the code if you put it in your profile model:

```
  validate :must_have_at_least_one_browser

private

  def must_have_at_least_one_browser
    if browsers.blank?
      errors.add(:base, 'You must select at least one browser')
    end
  end
```